# Ловлю ошибку от aiohttp ClientConnectorCertificateError

Tags: python, ssl, asyncio, aiohttp

При вызове асинхронной функции вылетает это. Советовали обновить либу aiohttp, не сработал

```
from binance.client import AsyncClient,Client
import asyncio
from utils import key,secret_key

key=key
secret_key=secret_key

client=Client(key,secret_key)
print(client.ping())

async def Cli():
     cl= await AsyncClient.create(key,secret_key)

loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(Cli())
```

Ошибку кидает следующую

aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host api.binance.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')]

Answer (score 0):

На Mac проблема решается тривиально. Запускаем  Приложения/Python/Install Certificates.command и все)